# Cannot upload using php scripts

Tags: php, html

I have a script in php that is used to upload files to a server. It was working first but i dont know why its not working again. It shows no error but the file is not still uploaded to the directory that i assigned to hold all uploaded files.  Here is the part that takes care of the upload:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
   {

  echo "Uploaded: " . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]) . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  //by default the size of the file is in bytes so u need to divide by 1024 in order to bring it to KB
  echo "Temporarily stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
  $target="/file/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]) . "<br />";


  }

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target))
  {
  echo "<h2>" . "The file has been stored on the server" . "<br />" . "<h2 />";
  echo "New storage location is : " . '<a href="/public/files/" >' . $target . '</a>';
  ?>
   <html>
<body>
<div align="right"><a href="/public/files/" >Uploaded files</a></div>
<br />
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
  else
  {
    echo "<h2>" . "Error while saving the file to the server." . "<br />" . "File wont be found in the uploaded files directory" . "<br />" . "<h2 />";
    echo "The error says: " . $_FILE["file"]["error"] . " What do we do now?" ;
    echo"<pre>".print_r($_FILES,true)."</pre>";
    ?>

<?
```

Comment: so does it echo anything inside else
   {  and how is form looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

`/file/` is a directory in the root of your server's filesystem, which almost certainly doesn't exist. `move_uploaded_file()` works at the filesystem level and has absolutely NO awareness of your site's URI structure. You probably want something more like:

```
move_uploaded_file(...,. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/file/');
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- add this
```

so that the file gets moved to a `/file` subdir of your site's root directory.